# How can an Android app access ringtones without permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I have Android 5.0.1(API level 21).

I'm using [NewRelic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newrelic.rpm) app version 1.9.3.(I can provide this version apk if necessary).

From update 1.9.4 their app started demanding access to [`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), aka "*Photos/Media/Files*" permission.

When I contacted the company for an explanation for this permission demand, they stated that this is "*required*" to access my ringtones/notifications stored on external SD card. However, I have always kept my custom ringtones and notifications on my removable SD card and I have always been able to use them in this app without it ever asking for this permission.

How is it possible that this app can access my ringtones without having this permission? Or is the company's explanation for this permission grab unjustified?

Comment: If somebody down-votes a question, it's customary to explain why...

Answer (score 1):

What most probably happenned is that with MarshMallow, Android have updated their cretificate permissions on their apps. Hence probably before this, new relic was able to fetch the ringtones automatically with a different permission.

With the latest updates, the app needs to access the external storage to fetch the ringtones, which seems legit to me. So the company's explanation is correct.

Comment: However, 1) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE states that this permission is `enforced` starting from API 19(aka Android 4.4).
2)I'm not running Marshmellow. My phone always ran 5.0.1
So it should not have worked, yet it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that NewRelic has messed up or your phone should be in 6.0. 
since up to 5.0 permissions are given during installation, only after 6.0 its whenever app is accessing a dangerous permission(which contain users personal data) that users have to approve the permission.

In this case if you are at 5.*, then NewRelic need to write the API specific code for below and above marshmallow as described
 here. 
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Your post does not answer my question. I'm not even sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: So what i meant to say is , its the way NewRelic has implemented its code,that is causing this problem, the link was for NewRelic team on how they can rectify it. Obviously you can't do anything here, as an end user.

Comment: I can't do anything "here", but as a paying customer I can work with NewRelic to address a potential problem with their app or even submit a security report to Google about a potential exploit that an app used to bypass security permission system. However, again, your answer does not address my question. You are just restating what I said in my original question.

Comment: What i meant to say is, that permission request was always there, however earlier it was requested at time of installation, which we do not usually see, now the permission is requested on when you are using that functionality like accessing ringtone, not at the time of installation. ..

Comment: Like I said in the very first line of the question my phone is running `Android 5.0.1(API level 21)`. It does *NOT* have permission request at first use, *ONLY* during install time. Please reread my original question.